# Image doesn't load from Firebase storage using Glide

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage, android-glide, firebaseui

I am trying to get an image from firebase storage in android studio but I am stuck and cannot understand the problem. The picture just doesnt load on the ImageView.

I followed the documentation that is on official site, but it didnt help, I also searched different question here but nothing helped me unfortunatly.

I have the user-permession for Internet in the manifest already

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

This is the ImageView

```
<ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/picProfile"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
....
/>
```

This is how the picture looks in storage

[image]

This is my code (Java)

```
StorageReference firebaseStorage=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("profile_pictures/2022_01_08_18_53_17.png");
                    Glide.with(getView().getContext())
                            .load(firebaseStorage)
                            .into(picProfile);
```

Also if I try to use this part of the code, the picture (sample_01)on the ImageView will be seen:

```
.placeholder(R.drawable.sample_01)
```

The question is what I should do for make the Glide show the picture from storage?
Thank you

**UPDATE**
I of course implemented the class

```
    @GlideModule
public class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry) {
        // Register FirebaseImageLoader to handle StorageReference
        registry.append(StorageReference.class, InputStream.class,
                new FirebaseImageLoader.Factory());
    }
}
```

and also in gradle the following

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.3.0'
```

Comment: Glide on its own doesn't know what to do with a `StorageReference`. Are you using [FirebaseUI for Storage](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/storage/README.md#using-firebaseui-to-download-and-display-images) and if so, can you show the relevant configuration for your app?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes I implemented the class MyAppGlideModule, and the gradle is updated as well, but it doesn't work anyway. I updated with other code required the question

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-view-all-the-uploaded-images-in-firebase-storage/  This is answer

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure what's goign wrong in that case. Hopefully somebody else spots it.

Answer (score 1):

I did face the same issue, so I move to downloadUrl instead:

```
  list.items[0].downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {uri ->
                       Glide.with(context).load(uri.toString()).centerCrop()
            .into(holder.binding.categoryIv)`

  }
```

Make sure to use addOnSuccessLister its important.